# Embeber el navegador Internet explorer en un form usando c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

estoy intentando meter el navegador dentro de un form pero no hay manera alguien me dice como hacerlo soy nuevo en este lenguaje:

c#

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
        web.Navigate("https://www.google.es/");

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {




    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En ese codigo no estas metiendo nada en ningun lado.. El navegador abre su propia ventana sobre el Sistema operativo.. para poder embeberlo en tu app deberias hacer muchas cosas a bajo nivel. Aparte de eso, hay un control de navegacion embebido en el framework. Cual es la idea de esto?

Comment: pues controlar la web desde el form , el control de navegación cual seria o podrías darme mas detalles o documentación al respecto gracias...

Comment: estoy aprendiendo :)

Comment: Hace unos años estaba intendando algo por el estilo. podrias probar este componente. http://cefsharp.github.io/ Aqui hay un ejemplo de como usarlo https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/details/how-to-embed-chrome-browser-in-a-winforms-application

Comment: Podrias explicar que estas tratando de hacer? el IE es un programa por si mismo, todas las recomendaciones que te demos no van a ser para el IE (y para colmo, serian recomendaciones y la pregunta seria basada en opiniones)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

paso 1.- cerrar el program.cs (no tienes que modificar absolutamente nada desde ahi)
paso 2.- abrir el form.cs en modo de diseñador
paso 3.- en la barra de herramientas (o toolbox) busca el control "panel" y acomodarlo en tu forma (este panel contendra el navegador)
paso 4 .- arrastra el control "webbrowser" de la barra de herramientas y colócalo dentro del panel

con eso ya tienes un navegador en tu forma, ahora el problema es la navegación y para eso necesitarás agregar una textbox y un boton de navegar

5.- arrastra el control "textbox" a tu forma
6.- arrastra el control "button" a tu forma
7.- da doble click al boton para abrir el editor de codigo y justo enmedio agrega esta linea de codigo

```
  webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
```

el codigo se vera algo asi :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

finalmente ejecuta tu codigo
escribe la direccion en la caja de texto y después aplasta el boton

--Adicional--

Probablemente despues vas a nacesitar que el panel se expanda cuando hagas que tu forma cresca de tamaño, para eso tendras que modificar las propiedades de anchor* o anclas.

Estas "anclas" hacen que cuando la forma cambie de tamaño la distancia hacia cada dirección sea la misma, de no ajustar las anclas el panel nunca cambiara de tamaño

Comment: forma sera el form o formulario? solo como nota, porque no suele decirse forma (o por lo menos, no que yo haya visto en algun lugar por aca).

Comment: Por acá se utiliza "formas" para hablar Winforms, y Formularios para hablar de HTML Forms o asp Forms (Formas para escritorio, formularios para web)

Comment: Mike gracias por tu contribuciòn pero ayudanos a responder preguntas basadas en [ask] para evitar contenido de baja calidad en el sitio.

Comment: vamos a ver yo quiero controlar la web a través de programacion como si fuese con selenium pero que todo este dentro de un form no quiero usar botones en el form

Comment: ¿que que? quieres hacer un unit testing?

Comment: estoy probando con lo de arriba y nada ...

Comment: hice una aplicación de consola en el que controlo una web desde un csv cojo las lineas y se los paso a una web ahora esa aplicacion se me abre el internet explorer entoces lo suyo seria meterlo en un windows form y que se ejecute directamente o no utilizar selenium pero como no entiendo la saplicaciones de windows form ...

Comment: sin ver lo que estas haciendo o lo que quieres hacer y con tu nivel de conocimiento me temo que sera imposible ayudarte.no creo que comprendas los eventos ni como se están invocando los métodos. 
solo te puedo decir que  webBrowser1.Navigate("URL"); es lo que provoca la navegacion, winforms necesita de eventos y eso es lo que hace el evento click, otro evento que puedes usar es el load que es cuando el winfows form se carga.

Comment: winforms no es una tecnología para crear o "manipular" o "modificar" sitios web, winforms es una tecnología para aplicaciones de escritorio

Comment: te recomiendo mejor que busques unos videos de youtube de como utilizar eventos en winforms

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80403/discussion-between-mike-and-ortiga).

Comment: @Mike ¿en qué parte se le conoce como "formas" a los formularios? desde que tengo memoria, se les llama formularios a los "forms" o ventanas de Windows Forms, incluso desde antes, desde VB6 y Access se les conoce como formularios, no "formas".